# How to run a SQL script in a multi-container app from a custom entrypoint.sh?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

**This is not a "I need to run a SQL script right after the PostgreSQL container is built" question**.

I have a FastAPI app with a dockerized PostgreSQL. My problem is: I want to populate the database upon app launch, but my tables are all generated by SQLAlchemy when I run uvicorn. So I need to be able to run the SQL with the INSERT statements right ***after*** uvicorn is executed.

To do that, I tried creating an `entrypoint.sh` file to run psql commands, but at the end of `docker compose up` I always get:

`psql: command not found`

I figured it's because Docker isn't inside the PostgreSQL container when it's executing `entrypoint.sh`, but rather inside the main app container.

`entrypoint.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

uvicorn backend.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 &

sleep 3

# Execute the populate.sql script
psql postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:5432/wikiprof
psql -a -f ./backend/populate.sql
```

`Dockerfile`:

```dockerfile
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /wikiprof
COPY ./requirements.txt /wikiprof/requirements.txt
COPY ./backend/ /wikiprof/backend/
COPY ./frontend/ /wikiprof/frontend/
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /wikiprof/
RUN chmod +x /wikiprof/entrypoint.sh
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /wikiprof/requirements.txt
CMD ["/wikiprof/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=wikiprof"
    volumes:
      - "/home/gabriel/wikiprof_bd:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres", "-d", "wikiprof"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 50s
      retries: 10

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: "service_healthy"
```

Is there any way I get inside the `db` container from `entrypoint.sh` and run psql? The main goal is running the SQL INSERTs upon launch, with no manual command running.

Am I technically doing something wrong or shouldn't I be having this approach altogether?

Comment: You can install the `psql` client in your container, if you really need it; that's probably a more maintainable approach than trying to "go inside" the database.  Making calls via SQLAlchemy or a similar database layer would be even better.  The setup where you don't know the database schema until the application is actually running seems strange to me, though; what leads to this particular setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried installing psql via entrypoint.sh and connecting to the database, but no success. I don't know if my conn string was wrong because I don't know from which container it's trying to run psql, but I'll try again using both `db` and `localhost` as host.  SQLAlchemy doesn't support running whole SQL files, and extracting commands using `file.read().split(';')` doesn't work very well because I have content with ';' characters. Nothing in particular leads to this setup, I just don't know any better haha. Should I just create the tables in the SQL file upon postgres launch?

Comment: @DavidMaze What I meant by my last question is: auto generating schema from ORMs should be avoided as a best practice? This is my first "big" personal project.

Comment: I haven't done much recent work with Python, but I'm used to setups where migrations are checked into your source tree, so they're predictable.  So try running `./manage.py makemigrations` on your local system, and then `./manage.py migrate` in an entrypoint wrapper before you start Uvicorn.

Comment: `alembic` is what you'll usually use for migrations in an SQLAlchemy-based application, and is the preferred way to what OP is asking: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/